# Are """ syntactic sugar for raw strings?

Tags: string, python-2.7

From a tutorial:

```
print """ Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
     -h                        Display this usage message
     -H hostname               Hostname to connect to """
```

produces the following output:

```
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
     -h                        Display this usage message
     -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
```

---

```
hello = r"This is a rather long string containing\n\
several lines of text much as you would do in C."

print hello
```

would print:

```
This is a rather long string containing\n\
several lines of text much as you would do in C.
```

---

Which suggests to me that the `"""` notation is just syntactic sugar for raw strings. I am completely new to python, so searching the documentation is not really an option for me.

Are `""" text """` and `r" text "`completely identical semantically?

Comment: "so searching the documentation is not really an option for me"-- you can always try first, and then come here when you fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

```
print """A\nB"""
print "----"
print r"A\nB"
>>> 
A
B
----
A\nB
```

Unless you use an `r` or `R` prefix escape sequences are interpreted. Straight out of the documentation:

> Unless an "r" or "R" prefix is present, escape sequences in strings
>   are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard
>   C.

You *should* be reading the docs, they're a great resource and the community is lucky that people have contributed to make python and it's common libraries very well documented. (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Raw strings and triple-quoted strings are just different syntaxes for the same thing: strings.  Triple quotes can be raw or regular.

```
>>> r"""\n""" # raw string
'\\n'
>>> """\n"""  # non-raw string
'\n'
```